# How to hide search icon when searched for something in css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I wanted to hide `search` icon when a user searches for something

even I want to hide `...` icon and clear icon to be left `x`  as it is

**Problem is shown below:**

[image]

**NOTE:** I wanted to maintain the same gap between `search icon` and `Search text`

```css
input[type="search"]{
  width:400px;
}

.more-symbol-3dots { 
    transform: translateY(-158%);
    color: #676460;
    right: 31px;
    font-size: 29px;
    position: relative;
    top: -2px;
  }
 .more-symbol-3dots::before{
     content:"...";
  }
 .fa-search.s-section{
    position: absolute;
    left: 13px;
    transform: translateY(11%);
    top: 10px;
  }
 .fa-search.s-section::after{
       content: "Search";
        position: absolute;
        left: 30px;
        color: #8c8585;
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="wrapper" style="position:relative;">
    <input type="search">
 <i class="fa fa-search s-section" aria-hidden="true"></i>
 <i class="more-symbol-3dots" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>
```

**Here is codepen:** https://codepen.io/eabangalore/pen/Lgrqxo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hiding the search icon can be done with

```
[type="search"]:focus ~ .fa-search {display:none}
```

Hiding the more symbol can be done with

```
[type="search"]:focus ~ .more-symbol-3dots {display:none}
```

```css
input[type="search"] {
  width: 400px;
}

.more-symbol-3dots {
  transform: translateY(-158%);
  color: #676460;
  right: 31px;
  font-size: 29px;
  position: relative;
  top: -2px;
}

.more-symbol-3dots::before {
  content: "...";
}

.fa-search.s-section {
  position: absolute;
  left: 13px;
  transform: translateY(11%);
  top: 10px;
}

.fa-search.s-section::after {
  content: "Search";
  position: absolute;
  left: 30px;
  color: #8c8585;
}

[type="search"]:focus~.fa-search,
[type="search"]:valid~.fa-search {
  display: none
}

[type="search"]:focus~.more-symbol-3dots,
[type="search"]:valid~.more-symbol-3dots {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="wrapper" style="position:relative;">
  <input type="search" required>
  <i class="fa fa-search s-section" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <i class="more-symbol-3dots" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks alot for solution, but what about `...` on right side one? can you please `hide` that too on `focused`  i,e    `<i class="more-symbol-3dots" aria-hidden="true"></i>`

Comment: Let me know still need help solving this.

Answer (score 0):

Style can be changed onclick as shown below:

```
 <input type="search" onclick="this.className='fa'" "/>
 <i class="fa fa-search s-section" aria-hidden="true"
     onclick="this.className='fa'" ></i>
```